# Resizing multi-page mixed-format PDF with Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have multi-page PDF-files with mixed formats A4 (portrait) - A0 (landscape).
Is Ghostscript capable of resizing the pages with size >A3 to A3 – but leaving the pages with smaller size (A4) not to be resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending long time looking for a solution, I found a great - and yet affordable - tool capable of doing the resizing and a lot more: PStill (http://www.pstill.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First, Ghostscript doesn't do manipulations of the input, you should read ghostpdl/doc/vectordevices.htm to see how Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device actually work.

Out of the box, no Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device won't allow you to produce output with differently sized media from the input, and different for each page (you can have it produce output sized to a single media size). It can, of course, be done, but will involve some programming, and in PostScript at that.

You would probably want to look at the pdf_PDF2PS_matrix routine in ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps:

```
% Compute the matrix that transforms the PDF->PS "default" user space
/pdf_PDF2PS_matrix {    % <pdfpagedict> -- matrix
...
```

Which calculates the scale factors required when resizing content to fit the media.

Also pdfshowpage_setup :

```
/pdfshowpage_setpage {  % <pagedict> pdfshowpage_setpage <pagedict>
  6 dict begin      % for setpagedevice
        % Stack: pdfpagedict
...
```

Which is where the selection of the media size takes place.

Comment: Thank you for the hint ...but will involve some programming...
Is there another way / tool you happen to know which can accomplish that with "a little less" programming?

Comment: Well, you could burst the PDF open, resize the pages you want altered and then create a new PDF from the individual pages. pdfinfo.ps will give you the media sizes so its is scriptable, but what you are asking for seems to me like it will always need some script programming at the very least.